# Python Matplotlib nonlinear scaling in contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scaling, contour

I'm having some trouble visualizing a certain dataset that I have in a contour plot. The issue is that I have a bunch of datapoints (X,Y,Z) for which the Z values range from about 2 to 0, where a lot of the interesting features are located in the 0 to 0.3 range. Using a normal scaling, they are very difficult to see, as illustrated in this image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O8hH.png]

Now, I have thought about what else to do. Of course there is logarithmic scaling, but then I first need to think about some sort of mapping, and I am not 100% sure how one would do that. Inspired by [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36830/logarithmic-scale-in-a-densityplot-and-its-legend) one could think of a mapping of the type `scaling(x) = Log(x/min)/Log(max/min)` which worked reasonably well in that question.

Also interesting was the followup [discussed here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102132/how-can-i-make-a-density-plot-or-contour-plot-with-an-arbitrary-nonlinear-scal).

where they used some sort of `ArcSinh` scaling function. That seemed to enlarge the small features quite well, proportionally to the whole.

So my question is two fold in a way I suppose.

1. How would one scale the data in my contour plot in such a way that the small amplitude features do not get blown away by the outliers?
2. Would you do it using either of the methods mentioned above, or using something completely different?

I am rather new to python and I am constantly amazed by all the things that are already out there, so I am sure there might be a built in way that is better than anything I mentioned above.

For completeness I uploaded the [datafile here](https://rbfi.io/dl.php?key=/X3sF/ThreeQubitRess44SpecHighResNormalFreqs.npy)  (the upload site is robustfiles.com, which a quick google search told me is a trustworthy website to share things like these)

I plotted the above with

```
data = np.load("D:\SavedData\ThreeQubitRess44SpecHighResNormalFreqs.npy")

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(16,16))    
cs = ax1.contourf(X, Y, data, 210, alpha=1,cmap='jet')
fig.colorbar(cs, ax=ax1, shrink=0.9)
ax1.set_title("Freq vs B")
ax1.set_ylabel('Frequency (GHz)'); ax1.set_xlabel('B (arb.)')
```

Comment: As a comment, you can for example see some features around 6.2 GHz and -0.6 B. This is something I'd like to make more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent question.

Don't scale the data. You'll be looking for compromises in ranges with many scaling functions.

Instead, use a [custom colormap](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html). That way, you won't have to remap your actual data and can easily customize the visualization of the regions you'd like to highlight. [Another example](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps) can be found in the scipy cookbook and there's quite a few more on the internet.

Comment: That's a great insight! I will go over the documentation and try to play around with that. Still, it is not entirely obvious to me that this will not just move the scaling issue to the colormap. The first thing is of course to pick well contrasting colors (and that too is not trivial), but then I still need to make sure that the transitions are such that the details I am interested in become visible. Say I go from blue to red in the range of 0 to 1, but most of my details are in the range of 0 to 0.2. Then I would still need some special scale for the colormap, right?

Comment: @user129412 I understand the question of whether this will not move the scaling issue to the colormap. But the colormap can be made completely arbitrary. To do that with scaling functions on the data, you'd be looking for piecewise continuous functions. You'll be much quicker done by changing the colormap. As for the selection, you could indeed make it non-continuous at the boundary (1: red, 0.2: blue, then grayscales for example) or just "stretch" the cmap: blue to orange for [0, .2] and orange to red for (.2, 1].

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. There is more than enough documentation on the colormap I think, so I should be able to figure that out myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to break the plot into 2 separate regions by breaking the axis [like so](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html)